# JSON.parse() does not work when content-type is set to application/json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, content-type

I am running into a jquery (bug/error) when trying to parse a JSON string returned from the server:

```
Timestamp: 10/04/2013 21:05:12
Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
Source File: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
Line: 3
```

and I noticed that the JSON.parse works fine when the header Content-type is not set to 'application/json' but does not work if Content-type is set to json. any idea why this would happen?

**Not Working Code:**

**Controller code:**

```
  $response = array('data' => array('msg' => 'Form did not validate'), 'response_handler_fn' => 'sign_up_response_handler_fn');
  $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-type','application/json');
  return $this->renderText(json_encode($response));
```

**Javascript:**

```
// ...
success: function( response ) {
var responseData = $.parseJSON(response);
}
```

**Headers**

```
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  92
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Wed, 10 Apr 2013 20:05:12 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=100
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.5
```

**Response:**

```
{"data":{"msg":"Form did not validate"},"response_handler_fn":"sign_up_response_handler_fn"}
```

**Code that Does Work**

**Controller:**

```
  $response = array('data' => array('msg' => 'Form did not validate'), 'response_handler_fn' => 'sign_up_response_handler_fn');
  return $this->renderText(json_encode($response));
```

Javascript the same as the one which does work

Headers:

```
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  92
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Wed, 10 Apr 2013 20:09:04 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=100
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.5
```

Response:

```
{"data":{"msg":"Form did not validate"},"response_handler_fn":"sign_up_response_handler_fn"}
```

Comment: Varying sources say to use `text/javascript` when jquery is consuming the json. I know it doesn't make any sense, but at least give it a try.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you don't specify the `dataType` option for the `$.ajax` call, jQuery attempts to parse the response according to the `Content-Type` header returned in the response.

So when you specify nothing for the `dataType`, and nothing special for the `Content-Type` header, `response` is parsed as text.

When you specify nothing for the `dataType`, and "json" for the `Content-Type` header, `response` is parsed as JSON (Javascript object literal).

When you specify the `dataType` as "json", it doesn't matter what the `Content-Type` header, the `response` is parsed as JSON (Javascript object literal).

Trying to pass an object literal to `JSON.parse` will fail, as it only accepts a string.

So you need to determine what things you're setting and what you're trying to call (`JSON.parse`), and use the right combination.

Answer (score 1):

if Content-type is set to json and pass the response as json then you need to set the

`dataType:"json"`

in your ajax.Otherwise it will not work.I guess its the problem.If its not shown your ajax also.

Answer (score 1):

@Ian answer is complete, but was somewhat obscure at first glance for me. 
 Just to simplify: if you specified JSON in both request (`dataType: "JSON"`) and response (`'Content-type','application/json'`), then response is already a JSON object, no need to parse it.
  Instead of 
 `var responseData = $.parseJSON(response);`
 
, 
just: 

 `var responseData  = response`.